# Как получить значение <select> для использования в Js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я пишу код для сайта с выбором криптокошелька в зависимости от того что ты выбрал в дропдауне . Пользователь выбирает криптовалюту и ему высвечивается номер кошелька при нажатии на который он копируется. Так как мне получить значение  для дальнейшего изменения текста с номером криптокошелька?

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="crypto">
     
        <span>Донат криптовалютой</span>
        <img class="crypto-img" src="crypto.png">
        <label for="donate" class="label">Выбор валюты:</label>
        <select class="crypto-dd" id="wallets">
            <option disabled selected class="crypto-dd-option-start">Не выбрано</option>
            <option value="0" class="crypto-dd-option">&#129505; BITCOIN</option>
            <option value="1" class="crypto-dd-option">&#128154; USDT</option>
            <option value="2" class="crypto-dd-option">&#128150; TRON</option>
            <option value="3" class="crypto-dd-option">&#128156; SOL</option>
            <option value="4" class="crypto-dd-option">&#128420; ETHERIUM</option>
        </select>

        <button class="wallet" id="result">Не выбрана валюта</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
    const numWlt = ['bc1qu6n3eu64jgmv5kvfq2egr5n8ml4svaf9uf8tnv', 'TS94K1icj8pNmYnYQ7r468LCu2c87XZcwF', 'TS94K1icj8pNmYnYQ7r468LCu2c87XZcwF', 'Cq9BhTNvvUCLX7maYVkUL3UaVjfM7Ec5EB5yF5ecWFpx', '0x4e58DfAC6Ed3fC130936BCA2CFe063DCddd5a745'];

const wlt = document.querySelector("#wallets");

wlt.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const res = document.querySelector("#result");
  res.textContent = `Номер кошелька: ${numWlt[e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].value]}`;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так получать кошельки:

```js
const numWlt = ['USDTRX34556788934', 'OMNI48867757499922', 'ERC20775848339919938'];

const wlt = document.querySelector("#wallets");

wlt.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const res = document.querySelector("#result");
  res.textContent = `Номер кошелька: ${numWlt[e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].value]}`;

});
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="wallets">
    <option disabled selected>Выберите кошелек</option>
    <option value="0">Кошелек 1</option>
    <option value="1">Кошелек 2</option>
    <option value="2">Кошелек 3</option>
  </select>
</div>


<div id="result" style="margin-top: 30px"></div>
```

Ваш код:

```js
function wrapper() {
  const numWlt = ['bc1qu6n3eu64jgmv5kvfq2egr5n8ml4svaf9uf8tnv', 'TS94K1icj8pNmYnYQ7r468LCu2c87XZcwF', 'TS94K1icj8pNmYnYQ7r468LCu2c87XZcwF', 'Cq9BhTNvvUCLX7maYVkUL3UaVjfM7Ec5EB5yF5ecWFpx', '0x4e58DfAC6Ed3fC130936BCA2CFe063DCddd5a745'];

  const wlt = document.querySelector("#wallets");

  wlt.addEventListener('change', e => {
    const res = document.querySelector("#result");
    res.textContent = `Номер кошелька: ${numWlt[e.target[e.target.selectedIndex].value]}`;

  });
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', wrapper);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="crypto">

    <span>Донат криптовалютой</span>
    <img class="crypto-img" src="crypto.png">
    <label for="donate" class="label">Выбор валюты:</label>
    <select class="crypto-dd" id="wallets">
      <option disabled selected class="crypto-dd-option-start">Не выбрано</option>
      <option value="0" class="crypto-dd-option">&#129505; BITCOIN</option>
      <option value="1" class="crypto-dd-option">&#128154; USDT</option>
      <option value="2" class="crypto-dd-option">&#128150; TRON</option>
      <option value="3" class="crypto-dd-option">&#128156; SOL</option>
      <option value="4" class="crypto-dd-option">&#128420; ETHERIUM</option>
    </select>

    <button class="wallet" id="result">Не выбрана валюта</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Внедрил скрипт. Не работает. Посмотрел через консоль браузера. Выдает это: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') на строке wlt.addEventListener('change', e => {

Comment: Проверьте свои переменные.

Comment: Вставьте Ваш код в вопрос. Без кода трудно сказать.

Comment: Вставил код в вопрос.

Comment: Не пойму, что у Вас не так? Я скопировал Ваш код ничего не исправлял и он работает. Посмотрите сами.

Comment: У вас изменяется текст на кнопке справа?

Comment: Я вставил Ваш код в ответ. Вы можете сами посмотреть нажав на кнопку "Выполнить код".

Comment: Может ли быть проблема в стилях?

Comment: Нет. Стили влияют только на внешний вид.

Comment: Тогда не понимаю, вставлю код один в один в vsc, запускаю через live server, но ничего не работает.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том что Вы используете скрипт в отдельном файле. Возьмите в самом конце html файла перед закрывающемся тегом `</body> пропишите тег `<script>А сюда поместите код js </script>`

Comment: Немного дописал кода  к Вашему javascript коду так должно работать в отдельном .js файле.

Comment: Все отлично работает с добавлением скрипта в конце html файла. С отдельный файлом по прежнему не работает, но уже не суть важно. Считаю вопрос закрытым, спасибо!

Comment: Тогда нажмите кнопку принимаю ответ.